# (C#, TLS) PseudoRandomFunction (PRF)

Tags: c#, ssl, tls

Здравствуйте. Пишу TLS сервер. Не могу найти функцию PseudoRandomFunction (PRF) для вычисления MasterSecret на языке программирования C#. Прошу помочь мне

```
master_secret = PRF(pre_master_secret, "master secret", ClientHello.random + ServerHello.random);
```

Использую CipherSuite: `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)`

Comment: Я вам ответил вчера со ссылкой на свой репозиторий, там есть эта функция, посмотрите как сделано. Можете даже сбилдить целый проект и посмотреть как все работает в режиме отладки.